# Why does the friend list in my Java program not display?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

Fragment of friends list

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {


private RecyclerView mFriendList;

private DatabaseReference mFriendsDatabase;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private String mCurrent_user_id;

private View mMainView;

private String user_id;

public FriendsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

   mFriendList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.listfriends);
   mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

//Path

```
   mFriendsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
```

// Recycler View

```
   mFriendList.setHasFixedSize(true);
   mFriendList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

// Return the main View

```
   return mMainView;


}
```

// On start

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Friends> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Friends>()
                    .setQuery(mFriendsDatabase,Friends.class)
                    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder> friendsRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>(options){

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public FriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            return new FriendsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.friendlist, viewGroup, false));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FriendsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Friends model) {

            holder.setDate(model.getDate());

            //Will get data from user choosen
            //final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

        }
    };

    mFriendList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerViewAdapter);

}
```

// End of method onStart

```
public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    public FriendsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setDate(String date){
        TextView dateOfFriend=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.friend_single_status);
        dateOfFriend.setText(date);
    }

}
}
```

// Friends class where I go get the string data

```
public class Friends {

public String date;

public Friends(){

}

public Friends(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

Image of Firebase database structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs0W8.png)

I don't know what is the problem. I'm new on Android.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are on topic for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to make it on topic, please do so.

Comment: @JoeC: that's good general advice, but it may be worth pointing out, in each case, which guideline you feel has not been adhered to, so question authors know what to fix. Is this Too Broad or missing an [mcve], for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the adapter for the RecyclerView.

```
mRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()); 
mRV.setAdapter(new MyAdapterRV());
```

You have an Adapter in your onStart() method. Make it global i.e public and add the line in onCreateView()

```
mFriendList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerViewAdapter);
```

**More about Recycler Views:**
In Android, if you want to show a long list, you can use a recycler view. A RecyclerView will inflate(create) child views and manage the scrolling up and down the list. 
A recycler view needs 4 things :

1. Reference from the layout file
2. A Layout Manager to tell it how to display the child views ( Your code uses a LinearLayoutManager that will display each item one below the other in a vertical list)
3. An Adapter that can take the actual data (your friend list) and assign(bind) it to a child view inside RecyclerView
4. A ViewHolder class that will store the reference of each child view

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didnt work form me, the app keeps crashing. :(

Comment: What's the error? Please post the error which you can find in the logcat window at the bottom.

Comment: @PaPankaj Sati , this in the one error that appears here: E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module and  E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout, I keep trying but nothing works. :(

Comment: when is in a activity it´s ok, but when it´s in a fragment, it doenst work, and i can´t find why :(

Comment: Hello again, already solved the problem, thank you so much for your time :)